# C - Stop method when SIGTERM is called in callee

Tags: c, fork

I've got a child process in C (created in fork) that can handle a SIGTERM call with a while loop like this:

```c
char* stuff = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
if (fork()==0) {
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler) //Sets stopit to 1
    while(!stopit) {
        shared_mem = doheavystuff(stuff);
        break;
    }
    free(stuff);
    exit(0);
}
```

My problem is, that doheavystuff() is called once and only stops when finished, thus when stopit is set to 1, the while loop won't end. Is it possible to just interrupt the execution of this method? I don't care about it's progress, i just want to clean up and exit.

Sidenote: It feels weird to me, that even processes, that don't get a SIGTERM don't seem to reach the free() section of the code. Maybe I did something wrong? Maybe they just don't get logged when they use printf()?

Comment: You have like 4 independent questions in there -- which one is causing you problems and why?

Comment: @Soren "Is it possible to just interrupt the execution of this method?" is the main question. I just got a weird feeling that maybe something else is wrong, thus the Sidenote.

Comment: Sure -- if you comment out the signal hander than that is the default action.

Comment: If `doheavystuff` is gonna be run once why you need the loop in first place?

Comment: I didn;t say to do anything with the loop -- just remove the `signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler) ` and the default is that the process terminates when you send the signal

Comment: @Soren Yeah, but i still want to free "stuff" when SIGTERM is called

Comment: @Xaqron My initial hope was, that the change of stopit (which is a volatile sig_atomic_t) would cause the while loop to break instantly. But i guess i was wrong :|

Comment: Then`doheavystuff` and `free(stuff)` should not be run on the same process.

Comment: @Xaqron Wait, but doesn't it have to be? Stuff is from before the fork()-call but still needed by _doheavystuff()_ and also has to be freed' before termination to avoid a memory leak. or am I wrong?

Comment: So -- that is what I mean -- you have multiple questions and they are not connected -- freeing stuff in a process that is terminating makes no sense -- so there must be something else the troubles you -- all memory is freed when the process termnates, so there is no memory leak in normal Operating Systems

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying if I send SIGTERM to the process and don't handle it, I don't have to worry about memory leaks / freeing memory. Yes? (:

Comment: Assuming your `OS` supports fork that would true for it's own memory but not always true with system resources outside the program's memory space (i.e. handles).

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag inside doheavystuff(), not outside.